# How to Set Up '301 redirect' from '/collections/all' to '/collections/all/shop-all' on Shopify?

Tags: redirect, collections, shopify, http-status-code-301

I'm just tryin' to set up a link as the *'301 method'*, tryin' to redirect from ***'/collections/all'*** to ***'/collections/all/shop-all'*** on Shopify, where when I click from the **'Shop'** button, it needs me to redirect directly to the page ***'/collections/all/shop-all'*** *(while the other one '/collections/all' doesn't need to work anymore)* but I think Shopify don't allows to do that.

Is that possible to do that?
(I know you can do directly from any of .liquid with HTML5, JS or Liquid).

Plz let me know at the comments, I really appreciated!

Trying to redirect from  ***'/collections/all'*** to ***'/collections/all/shop-all'*** on Shopify applying the '301 method'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean creating a redirect on `/collections/all` through Shopify backend you can't according to their [help center](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/menus-and-links/url-redirect#create-url-redirect). This is because it is a reserved path

To this date, the following prefixes cannot be redirected: `/apps`, `/application`, `/cart`, `/carts`, `/orders`, `/shop`, or `/services`

and neither the following paths: `/products`, `/collections`, `/collections/all`

Comment: Is there any possible even with edit with coding with liquid or java to force to can redirect on "/collections/all" to "/shop-all" in any .liquid or .js file?

Comment: Yeah I would suggest using the following Javascript: `window.location.href = window.Shopify.routes.root + "collections/all/shop-all";`. However, I tried it out and it looks like `/collections/all/<anything>` would just get redirected to `/collections/all`. Not sure why, have not found any documentation on that. If you can change your url to be anything apart from `collections/all/<anything>` the provided JavaScript will work.

Comment: Okay, I have a reference now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. `/collections/all` is the collection path for all products = not changeable
2. `/collections/all/anything` is the collection path for all products plus single product tag applied to it
3. to get `/collections/all/anything` working you need an existing product tag for at least one live product